# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Tuple`?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Here am implementing Tuple for using two models in my view.But am getting the following error

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
'System.Tuple`2[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcApplication1.Models.EventRepository],System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcApplication1.Models.SlideShow]]', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of type 
'System.Tuple`2[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcApplication1.Models.EventRepository],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcApplication1.Models.SlideShow]]'.
```

Here is my **View**:

```
@model Tuple<IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.EventRepository>, IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.SlideShow>>
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string SearchParam)
{
EventRepository objcheckout = new EventRepository();
objcheckout.GetEventDetails(SearchParam);
SlideShow SS = new SlideShow();
SS.GetSlideDetail(SearchParam);
return View(Tuple.Create(objcheckout.GetEventDetails(SearchParam), SS.GetSlideDetail(SearchParam)));
}
```

Any suggestion?

**EDIT:**
Here am calling two partial views inside my view and getting this error

```
 The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
'System.Tuple`2[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcApplication1.Models.EventRepository],System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcApplication1.Models.SlideShow]]', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcApplication1.Models.EventRepository]'.
```

Here is my **view**

```
  @model Tuple<IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.EventRepository>, IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.SlideShow>>
       @Html.Partial("EventDetails")
       @Html.Partial("SlideShow")
```

and 
**partial view 1**

```
@model List<MvcApplication1.Models.EventRepository>
```

**partial view 2**

```
@model List<MvcApplication1.Models.SlideShow>
```

`Answer:`I have answered this question(Edit)

Comment: You could (should) of course write a special (View)Model for the occasion...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
@model Tuple<IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.EventRepository>, IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.SlideShow>>
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
```

To

```
@model Tuple<List<MvcApplication1.Models.EventRepository>, IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.SlideShow>>
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
```

You're defining the model as `IEnumerable` yet you pass a `List` down in your `return` statement in the Controll Action (Index).  You also have the alternative to pass down the `IEnumerable` if you wanted to keep the collection from being modified in your view.

Answer (score 1):

For the new error, you can pass a specific part of the tuple to each partial:

`@Html.Partial("EventDetails", Model.Item1)`

`@Html.Partial("SlideShow", Model.Item2)`

But like @henk-holterman said, you should probably make a specific view model.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for my Edit is `@model Tuple<List<MvcApplication1.Models.EventRepository>, List<MvcApplication1.Models.SlideShow>>`

Since we are returning the view with two collection of objects as a tuple we have to define both model in partial views